# Let A = {n : n is an integer and 0 < n < 10} and X = { B subset of A | 0 < |B| < 5}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im having a hard time Defining a as a partial order on X.im I assume the maximal is a set with 4 elements and then minimal is a set with 1 element. 
 Let A = {n : n is an integer and 0 < n < 10} and X = { B subset of
 A | 0 < |B| < 5} . Show that B1 less than or equal too
 B2 if and only if B1 is a subset of B2 defines a partial order on X. What are the maximal
and minimal elements? Suppose Y = { B subset of  A : 0 less than or equal too *B* less than or equal too 5 }. What are the maximal and
minimal elements of # on Y?

Comment: Your notation is very unclear. What are you trying to do? What is "B f 1 A", or " #"?

Comment: [This link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) takes you to a guide for how to format mathematics on this site. Please use it to make your question more readable. As it stands, it is quite difficult to tell exactly what you mean.